# Instantiate C# class object using the string name

Tags: c#, class

Is it possible to instantiate a class object having the name coming from string?

```
string objectName = “abc”;
MyClass objectName = new MyClass();
```

I want the class object to be generated as:

```
MyClass abc = new MyClass();
```

Comment: Nope, that is not possible. What are you trying to achieve in general? I'd say that if you want do what you are trying, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: In the first example you declare a `objectName` variable of type `string` and then you redefine another `objectName` as a `MyClass` (this doesn't compile). And in your second code block your variable's name is `abc`. So what are you trying to achieve exactly? Variables are given human-readable names so we can understand the source code. Once your code is compiled, all your variables' names don't matter anymore. Your question is unclear

Comment: A variable name is a compile-time construct, it does not make sense to define it dynamically at run-time. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1386619).

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL It makes sense that it doesn't compile, so he asks here how to do it. What he shows is what he has tried.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I know that already that's why I put that in parenthesis

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL actually I want to get string variable from the user and instantiate the class object giving the variable name taken from the user. Something like this:

string userInput; MyClass userInput = new MyClass();

Comment: I think you misunderstand how programming works. This isn't possible and anyway there is no point of doing that. I suggest you to read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/344360) as suggested by @Heinzi . That's most likely your case now...

Comment: May be I did not explain the problem in a correct way, but I solved it using dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're talking about

```
Dictionary<key, value>
```

This might help you, do something like this

```
    string objectName = “abc”;
    Dictionary<string, MyClass> obj= new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
    obj[objectName] = new MyClass();
```

Comment: This is very similar to the already posted dictionary answer

Comment: This solved the task! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Dictionary<string,MyClass>

```cs
    Dictionary<string,MyClass> _dict = new Dictionary<string,MyClass>();
    public void CreateObject(string name){
        if(!_dict.ContainsKey(name)){
          _dict.Add(name,new MyClass());
        }
    }
    public MyClass Get(string name){
        return _dict[name]; // only demo without nullable check
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the concept I was looking to implement.