# Get type of class by string-Name and create an instance of it

Tags: c#, blazor

I have the name of class ex:"Car" saved as string, now i want to create an instance of it!
i think i have to get the type of it first, not sure!

Type.GetType() does not get the type with class name as input, even if it does how to create an instance of it next?

Comment: Please find an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598088/purpose-of-activator-createinstance-with-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an instance of a class from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instantiate C# class object using the string name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626870/instantiate-c-sharp-class-object-using-the-string-name)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.